# Удалить элемент управления с другой формы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, button

У меня есть 2 формы, на первой много кнопок (name заранее не известны), при нажатии на одну из них появляется еще одна кнопка (Удалить), после нажатия на которую выводится окно с подтверждением действия, где нужно выбрать да/нет. Если да то нужно удалить кнопку на первой форме. Как это осуществить? 
Буду благодарен за пример

Comment: `btnToRemove.Parent.Controls.Remove(btnToRemove);`

Comment: @Igor btnToRemove - здесь должно быть имя удаляемой кнопки, так? вот только я не знаю имен зарание

Comment: нет, это должна быть ссылка на удаляемый контрол

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Control controlToRemove = null;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // каким-то образом определяется, что нужно будет удалить. Например:
  controlToRemove = (Control)sender;
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (controlToRemove != null)
  {
    if (/* показали второе окно и пользователь сказал "Да" */)
    {
      controlToRemove.Parent.Controls.Remove(controlToRemove);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Немножко не то, но я доделал сам. Спасибо что направили куда надо!